# updating json value from a grunt task

Tags: javascript, json, gruntjs

I am trying to update a json value from a grunt task i have.

This bit of code works

```js
  var number = 123456;
  var setRandomNumber = function() {
      var fs = require('fs');
      var fs = require('fs-extra');
      var filename = 'my.json';
      var config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filename), 'utf8');
      

      console.log(config.randomNumber);
  };
  setRandomNumber();
```

What I want to do is update config.randomNumber to be the value of number.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example of updating the version of the package.json file using a grunt task. (from 0.0.0 to 1.0.0 to 2.0.0);

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('version', function(key, value) {
        var projectFile = "package.json";
        if (!grunt.file.exists(projectFile)) {
            grunt.log.error("file " + projectFile + " not found");
            return true; //return false to abort the execution
        }
        var project = grunt.file.readJSON(projectFile), //get file as json object
            currentVersion = project["version"].split('.');

        currentVersion[lastIndex] = Number(currentVersion[0]) + 1
        currentVersion = currentVersion.join('.');

        project["version"] = currentVersion;
        grunt.file.write(projectFile, JSON.stringify(project, null, 2));
    });
}
```

now you can call the task version to increment the file by writing

```
grunt version
```

or you can add it to your production process, for example:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('buildProd', [
      'version'
    ]);
};
```